# How to set an error message when search an invalid location in maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    EditText ed_place;
    Button btn_getLocation;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    double lat, lng;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        ed_place = findViewById(R.id.ed_place);
        btn_getLocation = findViewById(R.id.btn_getLocation);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        btn_getLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(ed_place.getText().toString(), 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (addresses == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    lat = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                    lng = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(position);
                    markerOptions.snippet("Latitude" + lat + "Longitude" + lng);
                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
                    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat + " :" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));

    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is my map activity.I use geocoding to get latitude and longitude of the location and mark it.When i search a wrong location app crashes.How to set an error message when i search a invalid location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
try {
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            Address bestMatch = (matches.isEmpty() ? null : matches.get(0));

            if (bestMatch != null) {

                LatLng ltlng= new LatLng(bestMatch.getLatitude(),bestMatch.getLongitude());
                Searchmarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ltlng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ltlng));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No result found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error search :- Wrong input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happens whenever we try to search a wrong location on map , for that you can put the searching code for places using geocoder into try catch block and handle the exception and show a message to the user for invalid search.